# AWS CodePipeline frozen on Source

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I have created a very simple pipeline. I have a git repo in CodeCommit, and the pipeline, when triggered, simply copies the files to an existing S3 folder which is set up to serve a static website. Once I finished creating the pipeline, it started an execution. That execution is sitting on the first step, Source. Its been 50 minutes now and it's still stuck on the Source phase.

Any thoughts as to why this might be happening? I don't see a way to cancel the execution. Are there logs somewhere I can look at to see if there were any errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There should be a log group available in CloudWatch that you can refer to for information on the error. Also, there is an Execution History tab available on the left hand side that will let you see any errors that are not logged to CloudWatch.

From the sounds of it there may be a problem with the source repo you have selected. It should only take a few seconds to read the repo. Very generally with AWS, many of the problems can be traced to IAM permissions.

You can cancel the execution by selecting 'edit' while it is running.